# Разыменовывание указателя в C и в С++

Tags: c, jni, c++

Смотрю на чужой код инициализации JNI в примерах из C и C++. Одна и та же строка в C и в C++ выглядит по-разному.

```
// C
if ((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void **)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK) {

// C++
if (vm->GetEnv((void **)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK) {
```

Почему в С пишется **`(*vm)->GetEnv`**, а в C++ - **`vm->GetEnv`**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так и задумано. Для C++ предусмотрен способ для более простого вызова методов. Но этот способ не работает для простого C. Всё это сделано для упрощения вызова: не надо разыменовывать указатель и не надо передавать this-указатель (в C++ он передаётся нахаляву).

Прочтите объяснение [здесь](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/other.html#30951)